# How can I get PhantomJS to set viewport height the same as document height for screen capture?

Tags: javascript, webkit, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs with its included rasterize script to automate a screen capture but I need the image to be the same height as the document, which varies.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found out what the issue was. There was an overflow-x: hidden coming down from a linked style sheet and Phantom was choking on that. I set it to visible and it worked like a charm. I did rewrite the rasterize from scratch so that there were no sizes passed, and phantom will default to match the viewport to the document height.